# Select last distinct records where table1.column1 = table2.column2

Tags: mysql

I have two tables from the same database:

Table READINGS:

[image: Table READINGS]

Table SENSORS:

[image: Table SENSORS]

I'm trying to create a query that will return, for each sensor registered in SENSORS, it's last row registered in READINGS. Note that the same sensor can have many registers in READINGS, but ONLY ONE in SENSORS.

The result should be something like:

[image]

Dump of the database: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85576999/redeSensores.sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95818/5

```
SELECT readings.*
FROM readings
INNER JOIN sensors
ON sensors.idSensor = readings.sensorid
LEFT JOIN readings r
ON r.sensorid = readings.sensorid
  AND r.`datetime` > readings.`datetime`
WHERE r.id IS NULL
```

Or if you need info from both tables:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95818/6

```
SELECT readings.*, 
       sensors.*
FROM readings
INNER JOIN sensors
ON sensors.idSensor = readings.sensorid
LEFT JOIN readings r
ON r.sensorid = readings.sensorid
  AND r.`datetime` > readings.`datetime`
WHERE r.id IS NULL
```

**UPDATE** AVG last day

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95818/10

```
SELECT t.*, 
   AVG(r_avg.temperature),
   AVG(r_avg.pollution),
   AVG(r_avg.noise),
   AVG(r_avg.humidity)
FROM (SELECT readings.*, sensors.*
FROM readings
INNER JOIN sensors
ON sensors.idSensor = readings.sensorid
LEFT JOIN readings r
ON r.sensorid = readings.sensorid
  AND r.`datetime` > readings.`datetime`
WHERE r.id IS NULL 
) t
LEFT JOIN readings r_avg
ON t.sensorid = r_avg.sensorid
  AND r_avg.`datetime` >= DATE_ADD(t.datetime,INTERVAL -1 DAY)
GROUP BY t.id;
```

**UPDATE 2** To filter aggregated records you can use `HAVING`:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95818/11

```
HAVING AVG(r_avg.temperature)!=42
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you very much! Is it possible to get the average readings from each sensor as well?

Comment: Average of a day? of an hour? which average?

Comment: Last day would be nice. I would like to know how the query gonna be.

Comment: Check update. and by the way my original query had an error you should change `<` to `>` to get last record. I don't know how did you check that :-) But doing this AVG debug I figured out that my query did get only first records not the last ones :-)

Comment: Too much appretiated =D Thank you very much. One last thing: is it possible to the query to return only the rows where a clause is not met? Like inserting a `where temperature is not -99` in the first and last query you posted. This way if a sensor has a registered temperature of -99 the query won't return that row.

Comment: @LuisHenrique so you want some particular value to exclude? or you want to cut some values over some limit? so if `-99` is not valid value, is `-190` valid?

Comment: A specific value must be the criteria. If the value is present in the row, that entire row must be excluded from the results. `-99` will be the value.

Comment: @LuisHenrique exluded from result recordset? so if my last fiddle we have `temperature2 42` and 42 is criteria all line with `temperature2` should be removed?

Comment: Yes. The entire line with 42 should not be part of the result.